# ansible vars_from in include_role does not find the var files listed under "with_items"

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run below on ansible ansible tower with ansible version 2.9.27.

```
- hosts: jdk_patching_list
  gather_facts: true
  pre_tasks:
      ...
      << dynamically generate following on remote server using shell module >>
      << /opt/oracle/opatch_jdk/jdk_patch_role/vars/12.1.0.2.0.yml >>
      << /opt/oracle/opatch_jdk/jdk_patch_role/vars/19.0.0.0.0.yml >>
      ...
      ...
  tasks:
    - name: calling jdk_patch_role
      include_role:
        name: jdk_patch_role
        vars_from: "{{ item }}
      with_items:
        - /opt/oracle/opatch_jdk/roles/jdk_patch_role/vars/12.1.0.2.yml
        - /opt/oracle/opatch_jdk/roles/jdk_patch_role/vars/19.0.0.0.yml
```

But it fails with

```
TASK [calling jdk_patch_role] ***************
ERROR! Could not find specified file in role: vars//opt/oracle/opatch_jdk/roles/jdk_patch_role/vars/12.1.0.2.0
ERROR! Could not find specified file in role: vars//opt/oracle/opatch_jdk/roles/jdk_patch_role/vars/19.0.0.0.0
```

I have been researching on this extensively and found out that there are couple of bugs in version 2.5 with same behavior, but it does not say if it's ever been fixed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The var files are specific to target server and are generated dynamically by th epre-tasks. I am trying to use the var files from the target server and not from within the role.

Comment: Please create a [mre]. The above isn't one. As a simple example we have absolutely no idea which task is firing the error and how the variable is consumed there. Create a roles with one simple task, call it with a simple loop so that anyone can copy it and reproduce the problem.

Comment: According to the error message, Ansible is expecting the files to be found in the `vars` folder of the role. Nevertheless your playbook worked correctly on `Ansible [2.13.3]` without any changes.